# Ionic 2 CORS issue when calling Google Places API

Tags: angular, ionic2

I created a new project using the Ionic CLI which is using Angular 2. I am trying to make a call to the Google Place API but I keep getting CORS issues. I am able to call the API and get data within Postman and Chrome but it is not working when I try to make a call within the Ionic application.

This is the current error that I am getting in the browser console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=steak&key=API_KEY_GOES_HERE. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is the code that I have in my provider after I tried to add some headers:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Place } from '../models/place';

@Injectable()
export class Places {

  private apiKey = "KEY_GOES_HERE";
  private apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })
  private options = new RequestOptions({});

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
    this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    this.options.headers = this.headers;
  }

  getPlaces(keyword:string): Observable<Place[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/textsearch/json?query=` + encodeURIComponent(keyword) + `&key=` + this.apiKey, this.options)
      .map(res => <Place[]>res.json());
  }


}
```

Why am I not able to make the API calls in my ionic application? How can I fix it?

If I remove the headers I get the generic CORS error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the CORS toggle google chrome extension. CORS is disabled for localhost by default in chrome

Answer (score 0):

The CORS toggle Chrome extension is great for development work but you will still run in to the issue when you move to production.

I've spent the last few days trying to find the cleanest solution for this with not much luck. Google do offer a client-side JavaScript library. But to use it, you have to hard-code a script file in `index.html` which I totally disagree with (think: what if the device doesn't have an internet connection, how would you handle errors?)

I also found that, Google have deprecated `JSONP` after moving from v2 of the API to v3 which sucks because that would have been the ideal work-around.

Instead, the only real solution I could find was to set up a super-simple NodeJS/Express backend which is configured correctly for CORS and acts as a proxy between your Ionic application and the Google API.

It was the first time I ever tried Node and it wasn't too difficult to set this up. I wrote a guide here: https://www.technouz.com/4674/use-google-places-api-ionic-3-simple-nodejs-backend-heroku/ and also created a sample Git repo here: https://github.com/zuperm4n/super-simple-nodejs